# Webshim: Initially hidden date input has wrong width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webshim

I use [Webshim polyfill](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html) to guide a user step by step through parts of a form. A date input is hidden at page load `style="display: none;"`. It's width is specified in percentage. Webshim sets the width of the input wrapper element (that is shown instead of the actual date input) at page load to a fixed width. It does not update the width of the wrapper element when it is shown `$('#initiallyHidden').show();`. But it updates the width if the user resizes the window. How can I trigger the update manually? Is it possible to trigger the update automatically on show?

```js
webshim.activeLang('de');
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {
  replaceUI: true
});
webshims.polyfill();
webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;

$('#showHiddenInput').click(function () {
  $('#initiallyHidden').show();
});
```

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.15.10/dev/polyfiller.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="">
    <button id="showHiddenInput">show hidden input</button>
    <div id="initiallyHidden" style="display: none;">
      <input name="initiallyHidden" type="date" class="full-width" required>
      <label for="initiallyHidden">Input was initially hidden and should have full width (100%)</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use visibility: hidden, instead of display: none

Comment: `style="visibility: hidden;"` does not work with jQuery's `show`.

Comment: use toggleClass or removeClass with visibility: hidden class

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it is a workaround. I'm still interested in a solution that works with `style="disply: none;"` and jQuery's `show`.

Comment: browsers don't do style calculation with display: none. but you can try to add full-width class on div too.

Comment: `$(window).trigger('resize');` will refresh it.

Comment: Or use the option `"calculateWidth": false` and use `.css` to define the width.